# How to add/register unique errno with corrresponding err message to Linux system?

Tags: c, linux, system, errno

Considering 'C' as development platform on linux system, I have an application that wants to set a unique and different errno than [predefined system errno](http://www.virtsync.com/c-error-codes-include-errno). Now suppose if I just assign a unique errno as **errno = 201**, then corresponding call to strerr(errno) will give me result as **"Unknown error"**, since this is custom errno, unknown to system

So How I can register/add this unique errno (say 201) to linux system.

Comment: If you have root permission, then you can add a macro for your errno and check.

Comment: This will just allow me to assign a errno using a macro.e.g: define errno as #define EMYNUM 201 and then use errno = EMYNUM.But when I will do strrerr(EMYNUM), it will still return me "Unknown error 201", Since there is no correspding err string, system is aware of.

Answer (score 4):

On a Linux system, function `strerror` is implemented by `glibc`

The source of the function is in:

- https://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.22/strerror_8c_source.html

The strings are located in:

- https://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.22/sysdeps_2gnu_2errlist_8c_source.html

The strings are all hard-wired in glibc.

You could grab the [source](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/download.html) and build it yourself with your error strings added.

The easier option however is to make your own error print routine that checks for your error codes and prints the corresponding string and, if it is none of your error codes, it calls `strerror` instead.

This has the advantage that your application doesn't rely on a modified version of `glibc`, so it is portable to other systems.

Comment: "*The easier option however is to make your own error print routine ...*" this isn't just the easiest but also recommended way, to not say the only *sane* way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LD_PRELOAD` trick to catch call to `strerror` and
you own result, if `errno=201`, see http://www.catonmat.net/blog/simple-ld-preload-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for the trick.However I am searching for some file, even if its part of system source, where I can add corresponding err string for my err code.e.g.: case ENOMEDIUM : return "No medium found" , case EMYNUM: return "MY ERR MESSAGE"

Comment: Then download it from here: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/, modify and rebuild